# Класс сервисы и DTO не видят класс @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Имеется класс с аннотацией @ConfigurationProperties. В нем находятся поля, которые подгружаются из файла. Данный файл хранит настройки сервера, и я хочу их использовать при валидации. Например, если длина логина меньше, чем указано в настройках, то тогда выбрасывать исключение. Проблема в том, что класс контроллер видит поля и позволяет к ним обращаться, а классы сервисы и DTO request не видят, при обращении к полям они все null. Подгрузку файла с настройками выполняю через аннотацию @Autowired.

Может, в классах сервисах и DTO имеется какой-то иной способ получения конфига? Или почему именно в контроллере поля видны, а в других классах - нет?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте аннотацию `@Value` в комбинации с `systemProperties` (внутри **Spring Context**):

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['priority']}")
private String spelValue;
```

или

```
@Value("#{systemProperties.myProp}")
private String spelValue;
```

---

Ссылка по теме: [Spring **@Value** annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

Аннотация `@Autowired` работает только для бинов в контексте. Если вы создаете инстанс сами через `new` или за вас это делает десереализатор то аннотации не работают.

Comment: Хм, а какой тогда имеется способ обратиться к полям конфига из классов DTO? Я пробовал даже явно передать объект из контроллера->сервис->DTO, но при обращении к полям все равно было null.

Comment: Никакого (не совсем правда, можно извратится и написать монстрокод). Имеено поэтому всю логику лучше размещать в сервисах. Там есть доступ до всего. DTO не должны содержать ни какой логики в идеале.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое! Только у меня и в сервисе нет доступа до полей класса конфига. Доступ имеется только в контроллере.

Comment: Добавьте, это не сложно. Просто скопируйте из контроллера поле с анотациями.

Comment: Добавлял, не работает. И не могу понять почему.